# Select all iframes inside the specific iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery: How to select all iframes inside the specific iframe?
I have a specific iframe, `id="main_frame"`
so far I tried this one, but it don't work:

```
$("#main_frame").contents().find("iframe").each(function() { 
  data = $(this);
  //somecode
});
```

This gets the data only for the #main_frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given HTML like this:

```
<body>
    <div>Outer Stuff</div>
    <iframe id="main_frame">            
        <iframe id="inner1">
            <div>
                <span>Some content</span>
            </div>
            <iframe>
                <div>Inner X2</div>
                </iframe>
            </iframe>
            <iframe id="inner2">
            <div>
                <span>Some more stuff in iframe #2</span>
            </div>
        </iframe>
    </iframe>
</body>
```

This script will select all iframe elements except the outermost one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {      
        $(document).find('iframe').each(function() {
            console.log($(this).html());
        });
    });     

</script>
```